# Show login information after login in laravel

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

Hi i am using laravel to login any user I have created my own user table and the code is as follows:

```
function login(Request $request) {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $rules = array(
            'user_login' => 'Required',
            'user_login_password' => 'Required'
        );
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
        if (!$validator->fails()) {
            if (Auth::attempt(['email' => base64_decode(base64_decode(trim($request->input('user_login')))), 'password' => base64_decode(base64_decode($request->input('user_login_password')))])) {
                die('1');
            } else {
                echo 'Incorrect email or password.';
                die;
            }
        } else {
            echo implode('<br/>', $validator->errors()->all());
            die;
        }
    }
```

Now I am showing the data in next page after login by Auth::user()->email. But is just showing the error as follows: So please help me to fix out the problem,

```
ErrorException in 0e5a47fe67787924c88247a752bd05e24b49d01c.php line 51: Trying to get property of non-object (View: /var/www/html/recore_web/resources/views/templates/administrator/header.blade.php) (View: /var/www/html/recore_web/resources/views/templates/administrator/header.blade.php) (View: /var/www/html/recore_web/resources/views/templates/administrator/header.blade.php)
```

This is my header.blade.php code..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title><?php echo isset($title) ? $title : (($this->router->method === 'index') ? '' : ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $this->router->method))) . ' ' . ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $this->router->class)); ?></title>
        <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no' name='viewport'>
        <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="<?php echo url('/'); ?>assets/css/base.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="<?php echo url('/'); ?>assets/css/skins/_all-skins.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="<?php echo url('/'); ?>assets/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <script type="text/javascript">var base_url = '<?php echo url('/'); ?>';</script>
    </head>
```

Comment: why are you die('1') I think because of the die the auth::attempt not able to put cookies and season try to return something

Comment: Yes you are right dear thank you so much... because of die It can not be able to write cookies and all others.

Answer (score 1):

Please verify if the route is under **web** middleware. Something like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function(){
    Route::post('login, 'YourController@login');
});
```

Web middleware provides sessions & cookies, which are required to authenticate the user and remember that in later requests. If that is the case, Auth::user() would be null.

You can also try Auth::check() before calling Auth::user()->email.

```
@if(Auth::check)
    {{ Auth::user()->email }}
@endif
    User not logged in
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your layout folder in that header.blade.php

You can find that code by just open "0e5a47fe67787924c88247a752bd05e24b49d01c.php" and look for line num 51.

If you use sublime text editor just Ctrl + P type file name "0e5a47fe67787924c88247a752bd05e24b49d01c.php and check line num 51.

In administrator/header.blade.php try to fetch data but object is not passed/created.

You can post your header.blade.php so I can guide you more.